# Problem with time series outliers

Tags: time-series, outliers

I'm studying [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3k8s76dq2w7b9bm/italy.txt?dl=0) time series (Italy - Producer Price Index):
[image]
Using TRAMO for outlier detection, I have found an **innovation outlier** on October 2008. Differentiating the series, this outlier becomes a **temporary change**.
[image]
Is it possible this situation? Do you suggest to cut the series from the **IO** or to linearize the differentiated series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IO=TC   When you have a stationary series and you correctly have differenced it

```
    as a pulse =[1-B] STEP or a STEP=PULSE/[1-B]

   or a pulse = [1-.99999]STEP  if the transitional coefficient is approx 1.0
```

actual/fit and forecast for ITALY

[image]

Equation suggesting 2 seasonal pulses with determinstic change in error variance (increased error variance at period 45)

[image]

Any attempt to seasonally difference this series will inject seasonality into the errors (slutzky effect) . Any software (or analyst) that suggests the need for seasonal differencing requires close inspection.